# Button Click is not working.View is posting message on buttons

Tags: android, button, view

Now i encountered problem while debugging my code,that the Buttons in my application is not responding to click action.I kept break point on Click view method but on click view method is not responding.

What i am doing in on Click method is, if i clicked the first button then swapping the value with empty button value.But on click is not responding.

Here is my full code to check.

```
public class Play extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{   
private ArrayList<Integer> m_buildButtonsIDs;
private ArrayList<Integer> m_gameButtonsIDs;

public static Character UserWords;
public static Character RemainingWords;
public static Character OpenCard;

static ArrayList<Character> ShuffledCards = new ArrayList<Character>();
static ArrayList<Character> UserBuildWords = new ArrayList<Character>();
static ArrayList<Character> RemainingBuildWords = new ArrayList<Character>();
static ArrayList<Character> RemainingBuildWordsAfterShowCard = new ArrayList<Character>();
static ArrayList<Character> DroppedCards = new ArrayList<Character>();

static Stack<Character>UserDroppedCards = new Stack<Character>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.play);

    InitializeBoard();  
}

public void InitializeBoard() 
{      
  m_buildButtonsIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  m_buildButtonsIDs.add(R.id.Button1);
  m_buildButtonsIDs.add(R.id.Button2);
  m_buildButtonsIDs.add(R.id.Button3);
  m_buildButtonsIDs.add(R.id.Button4);
  m_buildButtonsIDs.add(R.id.Button5);
  m_buildButtonsIDs.add(R.id.Button6);
  m_buildButtonsIDs.add(R.id.Button7);
  m_buildButtonsIDs.add(R.id.Button8);
  m_buildButtonsIDs.add(R.id.Button9);

  m_gameButtonsIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  m_gameButtonsIDs.add(R.id.pickButton);
  m_gameButtonsIDs.add(R.id.showButton);
  m_gameButtonsIDs.add(R.id.emptyButton);

  String random = RandomAlphabetGenerator.Random();

  for(int i = 0;i<random.length();i++)
  {
    char randomcards = random.charAt(i);            

    ShuffledCards.add(randomcards);
  }

  for(int i = 0;i < 9;i++)
  { 
    UserWords = ShuffledCards.get(i);
    UserBuildWords.add(UserWords);

        if(i == 8)
        {
            for(int j = 9;j < 52;j++)
            {   
                RemainingWords = ShuffledCards.get(j);
                RemainingBuildWords.add(RemainingWords);
            }
        }
    }   

    OpenCard = RemainingBuildWords.get(0);

    DroppedCards.add(OpenCard);

    RemainingBuildWords.remove(0);
    RemainingBuildWordsAfterShowCard.addAll(RemainingBuildWords);

    FillUserBuildButtons(ShuffledCards);
    StackingDroppedButtons(DroppedCards);
    StackingPickButtons(RemainingBuildWordsAfterShowCard);
}   

private void FillUserBuildButtons(ArrayList<Character> shuffledCards)
{       
    for (int i=0 ; i<m_buildButtonsIDs.size() ; i++) 
    {
        Button BuildButton = (Button)findViewById(m_buildButtonsIDs.get(i));
        BuildButton.setText(UserBuildWords.get(i).toString());          
    }
}

private void StackingDroppedButtons(ArrayList<Character> droppedCards)
{       
    Button ShowButton = (Button)findViewById(m_gameButtonsIDs.get(1));
    ShowButton.setText(DroppedCards.get(0).toString());     
}

private void StackingPickButtons(ArrayList<Character> remainingBuildWordsAfterShowCard)
{       
    Button ShowButton = (Button)findViewById(m_gameButtonsIDs.get(0));
    ShowButton.setText(RemainingBuildWordsAfterShowCard.get(0).toString());     
}

public void onClick(View v)
{       
    CharSequence text;

    switch(v.getId())
    {
      case R.id.Button1:

          Button FirstButton = (Button)findViewById(m_buildButtonsIDs.get(0));
          text = FirstButton.getText().toString();
          FirstButton.setText(SwapValue(text)); 
          break;

      case R.id.emptyButton:              
          break;
    }   
}

private CharSequence SwapValue(CharSequence k) 
{
    CharSequence empty = null;

    Button EmptyButton = (Button)findViewById(m_buildButtonsIDs.get(0));
    empty = EmptyButton.getText().toString();
    EmptyButton.setText(k);

    return empty;
}           

}
```

Here is my xml code for checking:

```
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="fill"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="115dp">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/Button1"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:text="@string/button_label"
android:textSize="15dp" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/Button2"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:text="@string/button_label"
android:textSize="15dp" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/Button3"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:text="@string/button_label"
android:textSize="15dp" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/Dummy"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/Button4"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:text="@string/button_label"
android:textSize="15dp" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/Button5"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:text="@string/button_label"
android:textSize="15dp" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/Button6"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:text="@string/button_label"
android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp" 
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp">

<Button
android:id="@+id/Dummy2"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/Dummy3"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/Button7"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:text="@string/button_label"
android:textSize="15dp" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/Button8"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:text="@string/button_label"
android:textSize="15dp" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/Button9"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:text="@string/button_label"
android:textSize="15dp"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/Dummy4"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/Dummy5"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp" 
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

<Button
android:id="@+id/pickButton"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:text="@string/button_label"
android:textSize="15dp"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/showButton" 
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:text="@string/button_label"
android:textSize="15dp"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/emptyButton"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:text="@string/empty"
android:textSize="15dp" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/emptyButton1"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:text=""
android:textSize="15dp" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/dropButton"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:text="@string/drop"
android:textSize="15dp"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/declareButton"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
android:text="@string/declare"
android:textSize="15dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Do you use the button's `onClick` attribute in the layout? If yes, please post the layout. Otherwise, you simply haven't wired up the events (either using the `onClick` attribute or using `setOnClickListener()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add an `onClickListener` to your `Button` :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(Play.this);
```

Comment: Thanks For your replies.But Changed little bit according to my program.